# Remove non referenced files from project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way in Visual Studio 2013 that i can remove non references files from my solution? I have had some issues with a backup script which has caused all deleted or moved files to be replaced with older versions from the old path. My project is healthy and working but i have lots of old files lurking in the project directories. I could do them manually but it would be very time consuming as the project is large and the problem has been going on for a long time without me knowing...

Answer (score 0):

If the files are referenced you can then either remove them with Visual Studio (Remove from Project), or you can edit the visual studio project (csproj/vsproj/...) and remove them there.

If the files are not referenced by the Visual Studio project, then you have no other option than to remove them manually. The only alternative would be to create a piece of script that will open the Visual Studio project to get the referenced files, and then it will traverse your dictionaries to remove the code files not referenced by the Visual Studio project file - this is doable.

Comment: What kind of script? where are the list of references stored and in hat format?